# How to draw a box on gazebo?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use ubuntu 12.04 64bits with ROS fuerte.

I failed to draw a box just only to draw a plane on the same button.

[image: image description]

How to draw a box?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51904/how-to-draw-a-box-on-gazebo?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2013-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sam you'll need to write an sdf script for your box, and have it listed in a models folder in one of your packages. The box is one of the basic primitives used in gazebo. Once it is written you should be able to place it in the gazebo environment. For ROS the packaged gazebo distribution is 1.0, though the latest distribution is 1.3. The list of gazebo tutorials is listed [here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials).

I think one of their first tutorials models involves drawing a box.

cheers

Peter

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2013-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2013-01-12**:
Why I can draw a box on ROS electric gazebo directly, but I can't do the same thing on ROS fuerte gazebo?

**Comment by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on 2013-01-13**:
sorry dont know the answer as i haven't used electric, however it may be better to ask this question on [www.answers.gazebosim.org](http://www.answers.gazebosim.org)

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-01-13**:
Can you post your model file?

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2013-01-13**:
My question is ' I don't want to insert any model file, and I want to just draw a box in gazebo,but failed'. I can do it in electric ,but not in fuerte. In fuerte, I can draw a plane but failed to go up to be a box.